# In Swift, how to use Layout Anchor to set multiple subviews to have the same width (no constant)?

Tags: swift, autolayout, interface-builder, layout-anchor

For example, I have a parent view that contains 3 subviews. I am using Layout Anchor programatically and try to achieve following layout

```
|--subview 1--|--subview 2--|--subview 3--|
```

Each of the three subviews has equal width. In other words,

subView1.width = subView2.width = subView3.width
subView1.width+subView2.width+subView3.width = parentView.width

I know I can possibly to use multiplier to set up the width for subView 1 & subView 2 as:

```
subView1.widthAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(contentView.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1/3).active = true
subView2.widthAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(contentView.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1/3).active = true
```

and subView3 can have leading anchor to be aligned with subView2's trailing anchor.

However, I saw somewhere that Interface Builder can actually assign these three widths to be equal directly (without using constant or multiplier). Is it possible to do the same with Layout Anchor programatically? And how? Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is the complete set of anchors (I've tried myself and it works):

```
// Create subView1
let subView1 = UIView()
subView1.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
subView1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
contentView.addSubview(subView1)

// Create subView2
let subView2 = UIView()
subView2.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
subView2.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
contentView.addSubview(subView2)

// Create subView3
let subView3 = UIView()
subView3.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
subView3.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
contentView.addSubview(subView3)

subView1.leadingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(contentView.leadingAnchor).active = true
subView1.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(contentView.topAnchor).active = true
subView1.bottomAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(contentView.bottomAnchor).active = true

subView2.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(contentView.topAnchor).active = true
subView2.bottomAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(contentView.bottomAnchor).active = true

subView3.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(contentView.topAnchor).active = true
subView3.trailingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(contentView.trailingAnchor).active = true
subView3.bottomAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(contentView.bottomAnchor).active = true

subView1.trailingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(subView2.leadingAnchor).active = true
subView2.trailingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(subView3.leadingAnchor).active = true

// Add equal width anchors
subView1.widthAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(subView2.widthAnchor).active = true
subView2.widthAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(subView3.widthAnchor).active = true
```

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: Are you sure it works or it's just a suggestion to give it a try?

Comment: It's a suggestion. Did you give it a try?

Comment: It's quite obvious, soI actually tried the same before I asked this question. Maybe I miss something, so if you have a complete and working answer, please edit your answer.

Comment: @JoeHuang I've updated my answer with complete set of anchors. I have tried this myself and it works.

Comment: Thanks, it works. I missed the trailingAnchor settings for subView 1 & 2. I thought widthAnchor settings would have taken care of it.

Comment: Anchors are internally converted into layout constraints by the system. Cool, @JoeHuang. I'm glad that it helped you. :)